# How I set Limitation in HTML form in timing

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I want to set limitation in timing in form input type my code is

```
 <fieldset>
           <legend>Time</legend>
           <label for="time">Workout Time</label>
           <input type="time">
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: What do u mean by limitation!? Pls specify the details

Comment: you can use this input type but note it works on all major browsers except internet explorer. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: Are you saying you want the time to be between certain limits?

Answer (score 1):

The input element with type of time can have a range of values specified using the attributes min and max.

Here's an example:

```html
<label for="input">Choose a time between 08:00 and 16:00:</label>

<input type="time" id="input" name="input" min="08:00" max="16:00">
```

Comment: I dont know why but it doesn't seem to be working for me..

Comment: Are you saying that running the snippet doesn't work for you or that some other code isn't working - in what way does it not work? If you put your code into your quesiton I'll take a look. As has already been said in the comments, it won't work for IE.

Comment: I am using chrome and it is not limiting me..

Comment: Thanku so Much for reply me
but,
I want to do something in such a way that no one can select more  than the minimum and maximum timing given by me.

Comment: Yes, and that is what the snippet does. If you put in a time that is outside the values then it shows a popup saying the value is wrong. I am using Chrome on Windows 10. Are you saying you don't see this?